# how to specify logstash config file when running it as a service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I can use logstash with the binaries by specifying the config file like this

`./logstash -f ../config/logstash-sample.conf`

But when it is installed rather than using the binaries it seems their site says you start logstash as a service like this

`sudo initctl start logstash`

How can I start it as a service and specify the same config file I would use if i were using the binaries.

something like this although this command doesn't work

`sudo initctl start logstash -f  logstash-simple.conf`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the config files are specified in pipeline.yml, it can be overwritten in logstash.yml.

By default it looks for all files in etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf

Created one there called logstash.conf and added my configuration in there. Needed to chmod 777 logstash.conf to allow permissions to it otherwise would not work.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the config file is specified (and probably hard-coded relative to some other directory) in your startup script.  Either change it there, or put the config in the expected location.